# is it possible to give an appropriate role in discord server with discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to realise the idea of bot that gives people possibility to choose their gender. Like someone types '!!male' or '!!female' and they get the role of gender they needed. Please help, preparing on node.js with module of discord.js

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
const role = <guild>.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '<role name>');
message.author.roles.add(role);
```

You can also read this [page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#legend).

Comment: I think OP wanted to give the role to the msg.author, not the mentioned user

Comment: yes, Karizma is right, usually i tried your variant but i receive mistake like: 'can't define 'member' ' like this

Comment: They explain you everything [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#legend).